# Export target property with absolute filepath

Tags: cmake

I want to export and install a library target from one project that has an additional property "my_special_file":

```
        add_library(my_lib INTERFACE)
        # my_file.json will be installed next to the exported .cmake target/package config files.
        set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERTIES
            my_filepath "relative/to/targets.cmake/my_file.json"
        )
        set_property(TARGET my_lib  APPEND PROPERTY EXPORT_PROPERTIES "my_filepath ")
```

In the consuming project I want to write:

```
get_target_property(my_filepath my_lib my_filepath)
# my_filepath shall now be an absolute file path
```

or in generator expressions:

```
set(some_variable "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:my_lib,my_filepath>")
```

How can I make CMake to export my_filepath in a way that it becomes an absolute path under the install tree? I don't want users of my package to concatenate paths.

Comment: (My riding-the-bus thoughts): Use `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>`, `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:...>`, and `$<INSTALL_PREFIX>` to help CMake compute the correct install path.

Comment: Excellent idea. That is something that I tried already and it results in: `CMake Error: Target "my_lib" contains property "my_filepath" in EXPORT_PROPERTIES but this property contains a generator expression. This is not allowed.`

Comment: Ugh, that's a weird restriction. Alternative: don't export the property, use `file(GENERATE)` or `configure_package_config_file` to populate a variable with the correct path, then use `set_target_properties` in your package config file to assign the property.

Comment: It was very simple in the end. Posted a solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution is straight forward:

```
set_target_properties(my_lib PROPERTIES
            my_filepath "\${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/path/to/my_file.json"
)
```

Escaping `${_IMPORT_PREFIX}` causes CMake to interpret the variable only when reading the exported .cmake targets file.

Comment: If you need to append to [`EXPORT_PROPERTIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_PROPERTIES.html), that could be worth mentioning and showing in your answer to help future readers.

Comment: Just so you know, this is a hack. It just so happens that the import prefix variable has this name and it just so happens that CMake does not escape custom properties. Either of those might change in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am still interested in a proper solution. Re-rooting filepath properties during install should IMO be a core feature. But i couldn't find that in the docs.